# Doubt regarding the moment of inertia of a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

In this system, I am calculating kinetic energy as:
$$ T = \frac{1}{2}I_{O}w_{O}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_{G}w_{bar}^2 + \frac{1}{2}v_{G}^2 $$

[image]

Being G the center of mass of the rod AB.

Note: A is not fixed.

Could I use the moment of inertia of the rod in A?

I understand that $ I_{G} = \frac{1}{12} ml^2$ but the exercise would be easier if I could use $I_{A} = \frac{1}{3}ml^2 $

Is this correct in this case when the point A is not fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  no, it's not correct.  If $A$ is not fixed and is not the CM of the system, then in general the kinetic energy of the system cannot simply be decomposed into a "translational energy term" and a "rotational energy term".

Let's assume a body moving in 2D for simplicity.
The motion of a rigid body can be thought of as the translation of some point $A$ on the body and a rotation about that point on the body.  The total kinetic energy of the body can be written as
$$
T = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i m_i |\vec{v}_i|^2
$$
where $i$ is an index that runs over the particles in the body, $\vec{v}_i$ is the velocity of each particle, and $m_i$ is its mass.  We can write each particle's velocity as the velocity of our "special point" $A$ plus the velocity of the particle $i$ relative to $A$:  $\vec{v}_i = \vec{v}_A + \vec{v}_{iA}$.  Written in terms of this the kinetic energy becomes
$$
T = \frac12 \sum_i m_i ( \vec{v}_A + \vec{v}_{iA})^2 = \frac12 \left( \sum_i m_i \right) v_A^2 + \left( \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_{iA} \right) \cdot \vec{v}_A + \frac12 \left( \sum_i m_i \vec{v}^2_{iA}\right)
$$
The sum in the first term can be seen to be the mass of the system $M$.  The last term can be shown to be $\frac12 I_A \omega_A^2$, where $\vec{\omega}_A$ is the instantaneous angular velocity about $A$.  (Substitute $\vec{v}_{iA} = \vec{\omega}_A \times \vec{r}_{iA}$ and apply some vector identities, where $\vec{r}_{iA}$ is the vector pointing from the special point $A$ to the particle $i$, to see this.)  So we have
$$
T = \frac12 M v_A^2 + \left( \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_{iA} \right) \cdot \vec{v}_A + \frac12 I_A \omega_A^2
$$
But to write the kinetic energy of the system as a sum of a "translational" and "rotational" term, the second term must vanish.  There are two important cases where it does:

- The point $A$ is fixed.  In this case, $\vec{v}_A = 0$, and both the first and second term go away, leaving $T = \frac 12 I_A \omega_A^2$.
- The point $A$ is the center of mass (CM) of the system.  It can be shown from the definition of the CM that $\sum_i m_i \vec{v}_{i,CM} = 0$;  and so the second term vanishes, leaving $T = \frac12 M v_{CM}^2 + \frac 12 I_{CM} \omega_{CM}^2$.

But if $A$ is not fixed and is not the CM of the system, then in general the kinetic energy of the system will include the cross term, and the total kinetic energy cannot simply be decomposed into a "translational energy term" and a "rotational energy term".